# How can I change the cqlsh (cqlsh_history) log file location?

Tags: logging, cassandra, cqlsh

cqlsh currently logs commands to ~/.cassandra/cqlsh_history
It would be really convenient to change that to /var/log/cqlsh

I'm guessing there's an optional cqlsh logging config file. I can't find it documented anywhere.
Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's impossible without some changes in `cqlsh.py` file.

From `cqlsh.py`:

```
HISTORY_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.cassandra'))
// ...
HISTORY = os.path.join(HISTORY_DIR, 'cqlsh_history')
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)  That sounds like a good property for the cqlshrc file, though.  Might want to submit a ticket to the Cassandra JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/cassandra/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous answer I just updated the history dir in cqlsh.py
Also added the user's login name to the filename.
Note that normal users won't be able to create the log dir, so it it's not present you'll want to fall back to default.

```
HISTORY_DIR = '/var/log/cql'
HISTORY_FILE = os.getlogin() + "_cqlsh_history"

#fall back to ~/ if central log dir is missing
if not os.path.exists(HISTORY_DIR):
    HISTORY_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.cassandra'))

HISTORY = os.path.join(HISTORY_DIR, HISTORY_FILE)
```